# Conditional Probability vs Joint Probability

Tags: probability, statistics, conditional-probability, machine-learning

I have a model that predicts the color of clothing items (red, blue, green, etc). I have another model that predicts the category of the item (shirt, pants, dress, hat, etc). Given an image, if I run the category prediction model and know that it's a pant, and then run the color prediction model to know it's red in color, what does that probability signify?

Does the score coming out from the color prediction model mean `P(color=red | category=pant)` or does that mean `P(color=red, category=pant)`? Or is it just `P(color=red)`?

What happens when I run the color prediction model only on those images where the category prediction model predicted a `pant`? Will the color score mean `P(color=red | category=pant)` in that case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the prediction means depends completely on the model and how you use it.

You could have a prediction based on the type of garment. Or they could be independently trained, in which case you *might* want to multiply the probabilities to approximate $P(pants, red)$, but that implies you are **assuming** that garment type and garment color are independent variables, an assumption I personally would not want to make.

If you want to get the conditional or joint probability, you'll need to set up your model and algorithm in such a way that this is what you get.

Comment: I understand that if the two models are trained independently, each prediction gives a marginal probability. So given an image, if I run color model, it would just give P(color=red). But I don't understand what happens if I only run the color model on all pants. Does that signify P(color=red | category=pant)?

Comment: Yes; if you train it only on images of pants, you would indeed get a model that is trying to approximate the conditional probability.